# Java/Eclipse - No more R file ever

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I'm on Eclipse for hours now and I didn't found a solution yet for my problem even after many searches on internet: I have no more R.java file on my projects.

On just created or on my old projects, i don't have R file anymore and I tried so many solutions (uninstall, re-install Eclipse, clean my project, check all my XMLs, fix problem with android tool and so on ...)

Please someone can tell me what to do in this case?

Comment: Do you have `Project -> Build Automatically` checked in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes i have already checked every possible solution that I have read on the internet =/

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using ?

Comment: open the problems prospective from eclipse. It will tell you what's wrong

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers the first in the download list on the official website

Comment: delete and import again your project

Comment: If there is anything wrong in Your .xml layout files, it could happen that eclipse doesn´t generate R.java. Check out all Your xml files, maybe there is something wrong

Comment: same problem, i got it when i create a new project

Comment: if Your code is not too big, please post your xml. Check out the "Problems" tab and post this here....

Comment: I just clicked New Android Application, generate all files and there is my problem. I dont have any code that its not even working for basic Activity

Answer (score 111, accepted):

> Hey If you just updated to ADT Rev 22 :

I had the problem too. There is a new component in the Tools folder called **"Android SDK Build-tools"** that needs to be installed.

**Step 1**

Open the Android SDK Manager

**Step 2**

Select the newly added **Build Tools** and install. (If problem stays then go to Project Properties => Java Build Path => Order and Export and **check** Android Private Libraries, then clean and build project.

It may be necessary to repeat the process, restart the SDK Manager after the update and make sure it looks like this (all tools installed):

[image: See the Build Tools in the image]

More info:https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/rCaeT3qckoE%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: Still the same problem even after updating

Comment: Even after Build-Tools are installed , Restart , Clean ?

Comment: Yes i've aldready tried all solutions i've seen on forums ; may be i am missing something =x

Comment: My Eclipse tricked me, i installed Bild-Tools but i decided to check again after its install and i had to install again the same package again but IT WORKS !!!!! Thank you guys for your advices

Comment: Open the Android Sdk Manager from folder(where android sdk is present)rather than from Eclipse

Comment: Together with external jar problem, I think android should publish a list of TODO list for developers after downloading ADT.

Comment: I agree. This should not be a confusing process riddled with pitfalls.

Comment: @Jahckyto Problem still persists for me as well.  Did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: Solved for me. I was trying to build a project that was working on another machine without any issues, but doesn't made gen folder with mine actual installation. Installed the Build-tools package and worked right after that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries you don't have:

- Android 4.2.2 (or other version)
- Android Dependencies ?

If so, then right click project - > Android tools -> fix android properties
and see if this library showed up.

Comment: Same issue, i have just an empty Android Application but same problem even with fix android properties

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for saving me! I've spent the whole afternoon on search this error.
Finally, my project works.
By the way, I also encountered one problem which i wanna share with you:

After upgrading, even if my project has not errors anymore. During runtime, it seems it couldn't find the classes from the jars placed in **\libs**.

Go into Project=>properties => Java build path= >  Order and Export.
Please make sure all your jars are **checked**.

Answer (score 1):

If this problem occurs suddenly in a well working project,

the first step is to find whether the problem occurs only in the current project or in all other projects.

if all other projects in the current workspace are working then 90% problem is with XML / mainfestfile/resourse file that you edited recently.

This error is not shown as red mark we have to find out what we have done recently in these files.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```

it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Close your eclipse and after refreshing system, try to open Eclipse again. I think you are using Emulator along with the eclipse. It may be because of the low Memory problem (RAM) of your system. I used to face the same problem when I use Emulator

Answer (score 0):

whenever there is any mistakes in any of the xmls the R goes missing when a build or clean happens so check for any xml errors in your project unless you fix it you cant get back your R on clean or build. fix the xml files and perform a clean you will have the R generated. Also check in File->properties->Builders and see if everything is checked

Comment: No error in XML and everything checked in Builders, still not working

Answer (score 0):

I was using Eclipse Indigo and nothing I tried worked. I ended up downloading Juno SR2, reinstalling the ADT, and now everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall everything and it'll work.. i.e. go back to Google SDK or w.e. you're using and download it.
Update it to latest in SDK Manager.
Go into Eclipse-Project-Prefs-Java build path-order/export **TICK** EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same kind of problem, however Rechecking all XML files in the Resources folder was helpful in my case. I found syntax error in my XML files. Cleaning and building the project again can be helpful sometimes too.

Answer (score 0):

problem: No R file get generated.

guess: Try cleaning project if it is old one. Else create new project with no R get generated and with no compile errors but this: `no project.apk`

In this case you have to check your SDK for the built-tools. May not be installed after updating SDK.

Thus download them if not [download here](http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-download-install-android-sdk.html), then put them under directory: `SDK/built-tools folder`. Lastly, and most important, is to *Run the SDK As Administrator*. This guarantees refreshing SDK with all packages appearing in it.

Install the SDK-Built-Tools or any missing packages according to the above link and you're done.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try one thing, create a new Android Project and transfer all those files which are in the previous project. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is error due to "&" inside strings.xml file(but error not shown) for declaring string for a array type. Now the problem has been solved as I changed "&" to "and".

So, please make sure that you do not have such silly use of symbols, and clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the dreaded not more R.java.

Some of the things I've used in the past:

- Clean / rebuild (the first thing we all try)
- Restart eclipse (optionally reboot pc/mac)
- Update both SDK/ADT eclipse plugin to latest version
- Create new eclipse workspace and import project
- Enable `Verbose` AAPT build output Eclipse menu>Preferences>Android>Build
- Port project to Android Studio / Gradle (this helped my actually see the AAPT error i was getting Error Code:138)
- Delete recent XML changes - Ultimately I found deleting recent menu.xml files I'd added and commenting out where they were referenced fixed the issue and I finally got R.java.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error recently and had found no fault in any layout or value file. After a lot of tries I add another Activity and the R.java was build and the error disappeared. I don't know why this occur, but it takes me hours.