# Android in Eclipse: Programmatically Assigning Nine-Patch to View

Tags: android, eclipse, nine-patch, r.java-file

> **SOLVED and contents edited for clarity.**

**Relevant References:**

[Android ADT version 22, R.java files not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585528/android-adt-version-22-r-java-files-not-generated)

[Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating)

[Create a NinePatch/NinePatchDrawable in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079868/create-a-ninepatch-ninepatchdrawable-in-runtime)

https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/wiki/9PatchImages

**Question:** How do I programmatically (i.e. runtime and not via an XML define) get a reference of my nine-patch into R.java so that I can call it from `EmployeeAdapter::getView()`?

> **Answer:**
>
> - To **runtime**/programmatically set the nine patch background **identically** for **ALL** View objects, execute
>     `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_fill)` inside of `Adapter::getView(...)` before returning the object
> - To **runtime**/programmatically set the nine patch background **individually** for **EACH** View object, execute `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_fill)` inside of `View::onDraw(...)`.
> - Be sure that your implementation of your `View::onDraw(Canvas c)` **does NOT draw over** your 9.png, e.g. `c.drawColor(color)`.
> - Place your file (blue_fill.9.png) in the **correct** `/res/drawable-*/` folder (to be safe!)
> - I have read that nine patch files need to be all **lowercase**.  (be safe, and do it!)
> - There is syntax to **define a nine patch inside an XML file** (I am unsure of exactly how to leverage this and is beyond this scope) but I can assure you that **I did NOT need it**.  In fact, I strongly suspect that my workspace woes ensued after I created `/res/drawable-mdpi/blue_fill.xml` and then linked it to my `/res/drawable-mdpi/blue_fill.9.png` with XML syntax.  This is probably wrong!
> - Feel free to borrow my **working code below**.
> - Because errors with /res/, /layout/ will cause all sorts of problems and possibly a hosed workspace, **be careful**  when editing
>     XML or other non-.java files.  **(1)** ALWAYS check LogCat, Problems,
>     Console output, **(2)** look in Eclipse's error log, and finally
>     **(3)** exhaustively look through your build config to see if problem persists (double check the new in ADT v22 "Project>Properties>Java
>     Build Path>**Order and Export**" and make sure that your source code
>     does not shadow an existing library **higher up the Order**!
>
> **Answer to my problem:**
>
> Due to a reason completely independent of ADT 22, My workspace was no
>   longer regenerating `R.java`.  I suspect that my messing around with
>   `/res/drawable-*/` folders caused my problems.  I removed all files
>   except `ic_launcher.png` from `/res/drawable-*/` to try to bring my
>   workspace back to a virgin state.  I also suspect that I imported the
>   incorrect R library (The **ONLY** one you should import is `import
>   com.example.yourproject.R`)

**Original Problem**:
I am able to use `bl_fill.9.png` with my XML-defined `GridView`.  However, when I try to programmatically assign the same `bl_fill.9.png` to my `View` object inside of `EmployeeAdapter::getView(...)` I get a compile-time error that `bl_fill cannot be resolved or is not a field`.

I have spent many days trying to fix this.  Any help is much appreciated!

**Environment:**

- **ADT**: v22
- **Android SDK Tools**: rev22
- **Android SDK Platform-tools**: rev17
- **Android SDK Build-tools**: rev17
- **Target API**: Android 4.1 Jelly Bean (API level 16)
- **Highest API**: Android 4.2 Jelly Bean (API level 17)

**Attempts:**

- Wrong /res/drawable-*/ folder?

I tried all pictures in one folder.  I tried all pictures in all folders.  The pictures seems to be sourced just fine wherever they are because `GridView` never hiccups about not locating a picture resource.

- Bad nine-patch?

To debunk that it may be a poorly formatted *.9.png, I have tried several of them (all of which I downloaded) and every one works on my XML-defined GridView.

- Successful Code:

/res/layout/**activity_main.xml** : GridView is defined in XML here, and I am successful in assigning the 9 patch `bl_fill`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:numColumns="5"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:background="@drawable/bl_fill"
/>
```

/res/drawable-xxhdpi/**xxhdpi-9p.xml**: I understand that this file is needed by the compiler to transform a "sourced" nine-patch (contains 1px border of control pixels) into a "compiled" nine-patch (adds a "chunk" metadata and strips all control pixels).  But more importantly, **I understand that `int R.java.drawable.bl_fill` should be generated from this file definition**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:src="@drawable/bl_fill"/>
```

- Unsuccessful Code (has been updated and now works):

However, it appears that `R.java` is generating `int` references for other resources, but just stubbornly won't generate one for `bl_fill`.

**EmployeeAdapter.java**

```
package com.stackoverflow.signinboard;

import java.util.List;

import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

// useful "Good Practices" for Adapters referenced at
// http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/
//
// also
// http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/
/**
 * An adapter that abstracts the structure of a database and safely exposes
 * information to consumers.
 * 
 * {@link GridView} uses this to obtain self-draw information for itself and
 * {@link EmployeeView} children
 */
public class EmployeeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Employee> mEmployees;

    public EmployeeAdapter(Context c, List<Employee> employees) {
        mContext = c;
        mEmployees = employees;
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Returns the total number of employees
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return mEmployees.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the specified employee
     * 
     * @param arg0
     *            Index of the employee in database
     */
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return mEmployees.get(arg0);
    }

    /**
     * Not implemented.
     */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the EmployeeView specified by 'index'.
     * 
     * @param index
     *            Index of this employee in the database
     * @param convertView
     *            Reference to a View that may or may not be initialized
     * @param parent
     *            Viewgroup that this View is associated with
     * @return An initialized EmployeeView at the specified index
     */
@Override
public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    EmployeeView employeeView;

    // Recylce reference if possible, else instantiate a new EmployeeView
    if (convertView == null) {

        // Instantiate an Employeeview with the ID and state
        // and define its parameters
        employeeView = new EmployeeView(mContext, mEmployees.get(index)
                .getmEmployeeId(), mEmployees.get(index).getState());

        employeeView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 85));
        employeeView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        employeeView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bl_fill);
    } else {
        // Set new values for the ID and state of this EmployeeView
        employeeView = (EmployeeView) convertView;
        employeeView.initEmployee(mEmployees.get(index).getmEmployeeId(),
                mEmployees.get(index).getState());
    }

    return employeeView;
}
}
```

Comment: did you update your adt to rev 22?

Comment: I edited my post with my environment and noticed the available 22 update.  Updating right now ...

Comment: if ypu have updated check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. might help

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thank you, however, I believe that the link you provided is for people who are encountering a runtime error of "ClassNotFoundException" AFTER upgrading to adt22.  Fortunately, I do not have this problem.  I did the upgrade regardless and my problem persists.

Comment: do you have any errors in resource files. cross check once

Comment: Just checked... no errors.  In fact, I'm OCD so no warnings even :)