# eclips project is not rebuild after clean

Tags: android, eclipse

I have map Project in Eclipse IDE and I Cleaned It From Project Menu.It deleted mY BIN Folder and also Gen Folder.Now I Have tried Much BY Build Manually and also from Android Toold To Fix Project Properties But It is Not fixing the Problem and In Source Files `R` is Red underlined and Bin and Gen Folder are Not Being Created again.Please any oNe Help me to To Get Out OF this issue.

Comment: Mostly one of the solutions mentioned here will help you out. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error). Always works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be Some Reasons :-

1.from Project-> checked Build Automatically.

2.There Should not any error in your xml otherwise R file will not build automatically.

3.Refresh the project & Restart eclipse.

Comment: Sir It Didn't Resolved I Also Created New Workspace But Here also `R` Is Missing.I am Irritating What Is The Issue With Eclipse IDE

Comment: check you xml file there will be problem. & You can try also:-
properties-java build path - remove all libraries except android x.x.
android x.x should not removed. & clean project restart eclipse.
basically R will not create untill XML have error.

Comment: Sir I Have Created New Workspace and android Project but Here Also R is red Underlined here is not any error in XML

Comment: check these link also:- some times ADT Plugins problem also not create R file:---
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update  &
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585528/android-adt-version-22-r-java-files-not-generated

Comment: `failed to find style 'mapviewstyle' in current theme` this is showing in layout file

Comment: remove or change your theme style according your version & clean

Comment: Sir Now There is No Error in XML But Still `R` is Red Underlined.What is Problem Now ????????

Answer (score 0):

First backup(e.g. zip) your whole workspace before you start experimenting. Then try to remove IDE specific files e.g. .project .classpath and setup it again. If it fails create new project with similar configuration and simply copy your libraries and source code into new project. Eclipse IDE is pure magic sometimes.

Comment: Sir Is there any way With Same Workspace ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported this project, then try import as a general project, not as android project. then in build path see if all libraries are present, then run as android application

Answer (score 0):

you have to try till you succeed process.
Try following steps:-

- Make sure there is no error any any of your .xml files .. check in
  Problem section..
- Make sure all your impoert are correct, Eclipse sometimes do `import
  android.R;` on its own, so remove that..
- If that doesnt succed make some changes in Manifest file say remove a
  word save it then again add that word save it.. I know it doesnot
  make sence as code but making changes in Manifest files rebuilds the
  workspace an so is the auto generated files. then clean build your
  project.
- Restart Eclipse as last resort..

Answer (score 0):

try the following steps to help us

remove if imported `import android.R;` and after like example if your application package name  is `com.example.project` you need import like `import com.example.project.R;`