# R.java file not generated after imorting a file from git

Tags: android, git, gitignore, r.java-file

Hello I tried importing a project which I recently cloned from github.As R.java file is among the git-ignore, The file not there when I import the project. After I clean the project many times and also build it manually many times, The R.java file does not get generated. please help me with this.

Comment: Note: The R file doesn't warrant tagging with the R tag (which is for the R programming language) - use r.java-file instead.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the `res` directory? Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16585897/2450152

Comment: @Gary111 no its my working code which had uploaded to github and it had no errors in res directory

Answer (score 0):

1. See if you've imported 'android.R' by any chance. If so, delete the same and do Project --> Clean. If still the error persists, then do
2. Restart the eclipse and do the project --> clean again.

Do you've any other errors showing up in your project other than R.java file ?

Answer (score 0):

The R.java is generated automatically by Eclipse, just Clean and Build the project, if that doesn't work is because your project have a error in your xml files.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add *import com......R" and then do a clean/build.