# In android project R.java is not created

Tags: android

I am using android sdk on Linux Ubuntu but when I try to create my new android project there is a problem - R.java is not created.

I am getting confused why it's showing such a problem.

Comment: Check your all xml files. They should be correct to create R.java

Answer (score 2):

This generally happens if there is an error in your xml files. Double check your xml layouts for errors. Additionally, try clean and build of the project

Comment: Thanx every one for ans my question.

Comment: I try But It not working.

Comment: Sometimes eclipse doesn't show you that there is an error in xml files, you have to check it manually i guess, line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build the project? Because R.java is generated only when the project is built, according to the xml files in the res folder, if they don't contain errors.

Comment: thanx for ans my question i build but still R.java is not creating

Comment: Have you tried to check the xml files in the folder res/layout? Probably they contain some error. If you use Eclipse and a file contains errors, you see a red sqare with an x before the file name.

Comment: I tried it sir but still problem is same sir. I create new project and then i run it showing following error


Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/home/trainee02/simmant/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory' while attempting to get adb version from '/home/trainee02/simmant/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools/adb'

Comment: So it is a problem with the adb. Have you installed the 32 bit libraries? Try to open a terminal and enter the command: apt-get install ia32-libs

Comment: Sir i am using 64 bit Ubuntu so this Libraries will work fine for 64 bit os sir???

Comment: Yes, adb uses the 32 bit version of the libraries, so if you run a 64 bit os you must still install the 32 bit libraries (that will work fine on your 64 bit os).

Comment: Sir But I want to ask one thing why this problem occur sir means is it due to 64 bit os or other thing sir can you please explain this please is will very helpful for me sir

Comment: Because the Android SDK uses the 32 bit version of the system libraries, even if you run it on a 64 bit os. So if you have a 64 bit os, you have to install the 32 bit libraries, otherwise the SDK will not work.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for kind help and such a nice solution now my sdk working fine sir thank you so much and it clear my all dout's about the bit of sdk Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

try to check ur android ADT UPDATE VERSION may this will help u

[Java/Eclipse - No more R file ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584015/java-eclipse-no-more-r-file-ever/16584243#16584243)

Comment: how i check ADT UPDATE VERSION Sir

Answer (score 0):

I very often come across the problem when I use capital letters in xml files names. Check that - maybe that would help:).