# Why my R.java cannot be generated automatically?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse on my computer. And I make a blank Android project via its wizard step by step. That means this project should work fine after it is created. But it cannot and show error of "`R cannot be resolved to a variable`". And I found that the `gen` directory is empty and it won't generate anything new in this directory even that I try to `Clean` and select `Build Automatically` option already.

I download an existing Android project from my Github and it can work. But after I run `Clean`, it gave the same Error information and its `gen` directory is empty again.

Why and how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: check your resources files if you have any errors. if there is any error then R.java is not generated.

Comment: if you haven't errors, open one layout and modify it and save then eclipse regenerate R

Comment: Here Its not because of resource error. Even new projects without any edit misses its R file. May be because of ADT plugin/sdk error, I think.

Comment: Check: [Eclipse error: R cannot be resolved to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable/16643060#16643060)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584015/java-eclipse-no-more-r-file-ever/16584243#16584243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed the followings in Android SDK Manager

> Android SDK Tools
>
> Android SDK Platform-tools
>
> Android SDK Build-tools

By clicking **Window-> Android SDK Manager** in Eclipse

Wait a bit to let it fetch the content and you will see if they are installed or not.

Comment: One of those tools is not installed, and I installed it. Then I made a reboot, the issue was resovled. Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

It is an error of Eclipse. Create a new Project, copy all the scr and res file to new Project.
It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1- Check for errors, if there are just comment it. The idea is to build the project et reconstruct the /gen. After that you can uncomment in good order.

2- Use Clean/refresh/build as many as you need.

3- Sometimes eclipse needs to be restarted..

4- Try to reinstall your sdk tools

5- If nothing is working you should concider reinstalling your ADT if you are using the bundle. If you are using classique eclipse reinstall android sdk retry and if it's still not working reinstall eclipse too.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times the error comes from wrong formatting in the **XML files**, which Eclipse doesn't always detect.

Make sure to go through the XMLs and check for potential errors.

If all looks good, **rebuild the project**.

If that fails **restart Eclipse**.

If that also fails, as a last resort - copy your project somewhere, **reinstall Eclipse** and Android SDK tools and re-import your project.