# Eclipse not generate R.java file after update

Tags: android, layout

I update some Android SDK in Eclipse (today when I open Eclipse this shows me a message asking for an essential update), and now when a create a new project the R.java file is not generated. I not have an import android.R, my layout files not contain errors and I try Project -> Clean.

Comment: Check the Lint warnings.

Comment: You might have better luck on the eclipse and/or the ADT forums.

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584015/java-eclipse-no-more-r-file-ever/16584243#16584243